# C#: Generic reference to Properties.Settings.Default.Save() for custom control

Tags: c#

I have a C# program with a custom control that exposes any generic properties.settings object. This allows the user to easily modify settings for the program.  I have done this for specific files but was looking to make it a generic control for any settings file. In this specific application I have a number of these files for different components of the application like:

- Properties.Settings1
- Properties.Settings2
- Properties.Settings3

The control is straight forward with a text box for the value, a text box for the data type, a Get Button and a Set button
In the custom control the calling parent form instantiates the object via a SetupControl routine:

```
    public void SetupControl(string in_thisLabel, object in_PropertiesObject , string in_propertiesString)
    {
        this.thisLabel = in_thisLabel;
        propertiesObject=in_PropertiesObject;
        this.propertiesString = in_propertiesString;
        lblProperty.Text = in_thisLabel;
        txtPropertyValue.Text = "Empty";
        GetDataType();
        GetValue();
    }
```

With the parent calling it as follows:

```
thisControl.SetupControl("Speed",Properties.Settings.Default,SPEED_SETTING);
```

I can get the values easily via:

```
    private void GetValue()
    { 
        string thisValue="";
        try
        {
            thisValue= propertiesObject.GetType().GetProperty(propertiesString).GetValue(propertiesObject).ToString();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            thisValue=ex.Message;
        }
        txtPropertyValue.Text = thisValue;
        _value= txtPropertyValue.Text;
    }
```

I can also get the datatype via:

```
    private void GetDataType()
    {
        dataType= propertiesObject.GetType().GetProperty(propertiesString).ToString().Split(" ")[0];

        txtDataType.Text = dataType;
   }
```

I can temporarily set new values using the following routine but cannot permanently save them as I don't know how to expose the Save() command. My understanding from other posts is that this is because the class Properties.Settings is converted to an object and is now an instance of the object

```
    private void SetProperty2()
    {
        // update _value string and do necessary checks on data type.
        this.UpdateValueFromTextBox(); 
        if (_value=="") { return; } // don't overwrite blanks!

        // Wanted something generic like this to work:
        
        var obj = propertiesObject.GetType();
        System.Reflection.PropertyInfo pi = propertiesObject.GetType().GetProperty(propertiesString);
        if (dataType=="Double") { pi.SetValue(propertiesObject, Convert.ToDouble(_value)); }
        if (dataType=="String") { pi.SetValue(propertiesObject, _value); }
        if (dataType=="Int") { pi.SetValue(propertiesObject, Convert.ToInt32(_value)); }
        if (dataType=="Boolean") { pi.SetValue(propertiesObject, Convert.ToBoolean(_value)); }
        //
        // Want the equivalent of Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
        //
        

        // instead need to first figure out which Properties object it is and set it via something like this:
        if (obj.Name==Properties.Settings.Default.GetType().Name)
        {
            if (dataType=="Double") { Properties.Settings.Default[propertiesString]= Convert.ToDouble(_value); }
            if (dataType=="String") { Properties.Settings.Default[propertiesString]= _value; }
            if (dataType=="Int") { Properties.Settings.Default[propertiesString]= Convert.ToInt32(_value); }
            if (dataType=="Boolean") { Properties.Settings.Default[propertiesString]= Convert.ToBoolean(_value); }

        }
        // repeat this check for very other Properties file....
        // if (obj.Name==Properties.Settings1.Default.GetType().Name)
        // if (obj.Name==Properties.Settings2.Default.GetType().Name)
        // if (obj.Name==Properties.Settings3.Default.GetType().Name)
    }
```

How can i generically reference a settings file via something like:

Properties.[mySettingFileStringVariable].Default.Save()

Comment: Project > Properties > Settings tab, change the "Access Modifier" from Internal to Public.

Comment: Or, better, have your main app call Save() at program exit.  Much safer that way, a bad setting value that crashes the app won't crash it over and over again with no easy way for the user to fix the problem.

Comment: If you want to access custom [Setting].settings files by name, you can write, e.g., `var customSettings = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None).GetSectionGroup("userSettings").Sections["<setting full name>"] as ClientSettingsSection;`, where `<setting full name>` is the settings name as specified in the `[your app].exe.config` file. To access a property by name, then it's `var propValue = customSettings?.Settings.Get("<SettingName>");` <- If you want to set the Value, note that it's an XmlNode, so you need set the value on a copy, then set the XmlNode back

Comment: Can be `[your app].dll.config` if you're building a .NET 6+ application -- BTW, you should always specify what kind of application you're building and the target .NET version and tag the question accordingly. A *C# program with a custom control* doesn't mean anything per se, people have to infer the application type based on the objects you declare in your partial code, which can lead to wrong assumptions, which means a waste of time for everyone